# Automating magit

Tags: automation

How can I do this more efficiently, assuming I do this hundreds of times a day - it becomes tedious.

```
# while editing a source code file
M-x magit-stage-file
M-x magit-commit
type in wip
C-c to confirm
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to write a command that wraps those actions:

```
(defun anw/magit-commit-file-wip ()
  (interactive)
  (magit-with-toplevel
    (let ((file (or (magit-current-file)
                    (user-error "No current file"))))
      (magit-stage-file file)
      (magit-run-git "commit" "--message=wip" "--" file))))
```

If you want to operate on tracked files only, you could drop the `magit-stage-file` call above.  And if you want to include staged changes from other files in the commit, you can drop the file argument to `git commit` and add `--all` instead.

Also, you may want to have a look at both `magit-file-popup` and Magit's WIP modes if you don't already use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `magit-status` buffer. Run `M-x magit-status`, and a buffer will open showing the status of the project.

You can move point to the source file and press `s` to stage it -- or even move to just one chunk in the file to stage it but not other changes ih the file.

You can then commit with `c c`, and it'll prompt for the message. You can commit with `C-c C-c`.

Note that you can always have the `magit-status` buffer open; if you switch back to it and press `g`, it'll refresh to show you the latest status.

So the entire procedure is this:

```
C-x b *magit: project <ret> #or however you switch to the buffer
g #refresh the view
nnnn #move to the buffer you changed, assuming you're at the top of the buffer.
s #stage the changes in that buffer
cc #open the commit window
<write commmit message>
C-c C-c #commit it!
```